# Old intent in activity started from notification

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, android-notifications

I'm creating intent like this

```
val tapIntent = Intent(context, TaskActivity::class.java).apply {
    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
}
val id = createID()
tapIntent.putExtra("timestamp", currentTime)
val notificationIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, tapIntent, 0)
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "com.task")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
    .setContentTitle(context.resources.getString(R.string.new_task_available))
    .setContentIntent(notificationIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
    notify(id, builder.build())
}
```

This notifications are generated few times a day.
And when testing it, I've found out that if I'm not closing activity, but just swiping out of it, next time I open this activity from intent, I see that intent stores timestamp of a previous notification and not a current one.

Code for reading data from intent is quite simple:

```
val timestamp = intent.getLongExtra("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis())
val hourFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
Toast.makeText(this, hourFormatter.format(Date(timestamp)), LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

As far as I understand `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` should clear all the old info. So I don't understand why this is happening.
What sould I do to receive current intent instead of the original one?

Comment: Did you try overriding the `onNewIntent` method in the Activity and using that data?

Comment: @Kilian  in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) it says that this method only works for `Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, which I don't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When generating the `PendingIntent` for the `Notification`, you need to do this:

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, tapIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

Otherwise you will just be using the previous (old) `PendingIntent` instead of creating a new one.